# Exception with web service ( java.net.SocketException Permission denied ) in Android

Tags: android, web-services, socketexception

When I call a Web Service, it returns me this exception: java.net.SocketException Permission denied. I dont know waht is the actual problem. I don't know how to solve this?

home.java page :

```
     try 
     { 
       url = new URL("http://localhost/TraderLevels/subscriber.php");
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             dis = conn.getInputStream();
     }
     catch (Exception e) 
     {
            e.printStackTrace();

     }
```

subscriber.php

```
$username="root";
        $password="";
        $database="mydb";
        $server="localhost";

$connection = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);

 if (!$connection)
 {
   die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
 }

 $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);


 if (!$db_selected)
 {
   die('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
 }


    $query="SELECT * from user";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $dnode = $dom->createElement('usesssrdetails');

    $docNode = $dom->appendChild($dnode);

    $result = mysql_query($query);
   $rowNo=1;

  while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {

  $node = $dom->createElement('user');
  $categoryNode = $docNode->appendChild($node);

  $idNode = $dom->createElement('userid',($row['userID']));
  $categoryNode->appendChild($idNode);
                $idNode = $dom->createElement('email',($row['email']));
  $categoryNode->appendChild($idNode);


  $rowNo=$rowNo+1;
 }
 $kmlOutput = $dom->saveXML();
 echo $kmlOutput;

?>
```

#### Update:

I solved  the above problem by adding  the below code in the manifest.

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But I got another exception : 
java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection Refused.

Please tell me how to avoid this problem.

Comment: Have you include the web permission in your manifest ?

Comment: thank you so much xandy... Your suggestion removes the SocketException. But I got another exception : java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection Refused. Please tell me how to avoid this also...

Answer (score 4):

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias

ifconfig

get the real network address instead of loopback and use that real network adress.

Comment: The URL does not exist any more.

Comment: PS: Here's a new one: http://www.droidnova.com/ever-tried-localhost-with-the-android-emulator,102.html (in short: Use the IP 10.0.2.2)

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually running a webserver on localhost?

If so, have you verified it's listening with netstat and actually tested it with a known-working client such as the browser or netcat (nc)?

And do you realize that localhost means the android device itself?  If the server is running on a development machine hosting an emulator, you need to use the special alias address for the development machine loopback instead.  If your app is running on an actual phone, it's even more complicated to contact a server on your pc, unless you go via wifi or set up USB tethering.

Answer (score 1):

I just change to my ethernet IP Address 192.168.1.80 instead of using "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", and it works ...

Answer (score 0):

i got that solution. i changed the configuration file of Apache Server. (I have celled a web service that is in php)